Setting aliases when creating Conda environment
Is it possible to include an alias in a conda YAML file, so when you create the environment from the YAML you set the alias? I have a Snakemake workflow that works in a Conda environment and I would like to wrap the long snakemake command into the workflow name, like:
alias workflow_name='snakemake long command'

I've seen it's possible to set environment variables in the YAML, but I'm not sure aobut aliases
